# Kendo DataSource create method not getting called

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Why is my transport's create method not being called when I click the "Save Changes" button on the grid? Everything appears to be working except my controller code for create isn't getting called.

Kendo Code:

```
   var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                cached: false,
                url: '@Url.Action("GetListOfFacilities", "Tactic")',
                dataType: "json"
            }
        }

    });

    var OrgdataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: '@Url.Action("ReadOrganizations", "Tactic")',
                dataType: "json"
            },
            create: {
                url: '@Url.Action("AddOrganization", "Tactic")',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        batch: false
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "id",
                fields: {
                    id: { type: "string", editable: false },
                    Name: { type: "string" }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $("#FacilityGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: OrgdataSource,
        autoBind: true,
        autoSync: true,
        editable: { mode: "inline" },
        selectable: true,
        toolbar: ["save", "create"],
        columns: [
            { command: ["destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "150px" },
            { field: "Name", title: "Facility Name", editor: OrgDropDownEditor },
        ]
    });


    function OrgDropDownEditor (container, options) {
        $('<input required data-text-field="Text" data-value-field="Value" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
            .appendTo(container)
            .kendoDropDownList({
                autoBind: true,
                dataSource: ds
            });
    }
```

Controller Code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddOrganization(SelectListItem selectedOrg)
    {
        ...
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string GetListOfFacilities()
    {
        var lst = new List<SelectListItem>();
        lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "Facility 1" });
        lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "Facility 2" });
        lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "Facility 3" });
        lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "4", Text = "Facility 4" });
        lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "5", Text = "Facility 5" });

        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(lst);
        return json;
    }
```

Comment: if I set OrgdataSource's  id field to editable, my controller code gets called. But I can't allow that field to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "id" from the fields object.  It doesn't need to be in there if you have specified it as the id of the model.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that still didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Just noticed you have autosync set to true.  That will automatically try and save records back to the dataSource.  I think it also disables the manual saving functionality.  If you want your users to click a button to save you should set this to false.

Comment: This is how i have been setting up grids when using js and not MVVM bindings:

`$("#scheduleEquipmentXSGrid").kendoGrid({  

   dataSource: viewModel.equipmentXSDataSource,  

   editable: true,  

   toolbar: ['create'],  

   editable: { mode: 'popup', template: kendo.template($("#eqPopTemplate").html()) },  
   columns:
   [ 
   ]  `

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem like this. I have resolved it by defining a default value for my model fields. In your model you should provide a default value for `Name` field to prevent passing null to datasource.

```
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "id",
            fields: {
                id: { type: "string", editable: false },
                Name: { type: "string" }
            }
        }
    }
```